# How do I use pickit 2

Tags: c++, microcontroller, pic, circuit

Hey everyone
I have a pickit 2 and I am a bit confused about the wiring to the micro-controller. I found what each pin is but I was wondering if I just directly wire them or if I need to use any capacitors or diodes. If you can supply a diagram that would be nice also.

Comment: it seems that this question would be much more suited for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ although even then it's not quite clear to me what you are actually trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, the PICKIT 2 is a demo board and comes power on ready. If you're referring to using the programmer on a custom board, the simplest way is to mimic the layout of the demo board. Microchip normally offers schematics for all their demo boards and generally has the best documentation I've ever seen for any MCU.